# How to generate a context sensitive grammar for www

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, context-sensitive

I am trying to solve for my exam coming up and have no clue how to generate the grammar for Context sensitive languages
for example how do i proceed on this kind of question.

> Give a context-sensitive (not just length-increasing) grammar for $\{www : w ∈ \{a, b\}^⋆\}$.

Ideas or approaches on how to deal with this kind of questions is much appreciated.

Comment: Idea: every time you generate an "a", generate also "a'" and "a''" (same goes with "b"s). Now, a'' can switch with a non-primed letter to its right (but not with a primed, or doubled primed one.). At the end, get rid of the primes.

Comment: Hint: "www" is not context-free so you'll *have* to make use of the additional facilities context-sensitive grammars give you. A common theme is *switching* non-terminal, effectively moving them around the sentence. Hence, it's easy to simular a TM head with the grammar. How would you decide "www" algorithmically?

Answer (score 5):

Intuitively you want to generate three intermediate symbols at a time, and allow the symbols to sort themselves. Let $S$ be the start symbol. The generation rules are:

$$S \rightarrow S A_1 A_2 A_3$$
$$S \rightarrow S B_1 B_2 B_3$$
The sorting rules are as follows: For symbols $X_i,Y_i \in \{A_1,A_2,A_3,B_1,B_2,B_3\}$ such that $j < i$ add the rule:
$$X_i Y_j \rightarrow Y_jX_i$$
In the end we have to turn the intermediate symbols into terminal symbols. Turn the start symbol into another symbol $S_1$ to end the generation phase. 
$$S \rightarrow S_1$$
Push $S_1$ through the string converting symbols to terminal symbols on the way and increment the subscript when done with one word $w$.
For all $i \in \{1,2,3\}$ add the rules:
$$S_i A_i \rightarrow a S_i \; | \; a S_{i+1}$$
$$S_i B_i \rightarrow b S_i \; | \; b S_{i+1}$$
The subscript of $S$ ensures that the symbols are converted in the proper order as the subscript can not decrease. In the end remove $S_3$.
$$ S_3 \rightarrow \varepsilon $$

Comment: Although your grammar comes close, it is neither contextsensitive (which User_1234 asked for) due to rules such as "$AB \rightarrow BA$" nor monotone due to $S_3 \rightarrow \epsilon$.

Comment: @lukas.coenig The epsilon rule is indeed not allowed (should be easy to fix), but otherwise the grammar is in [Kuroda normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuroda_normal_form). Not every definition of CSGs admit it, but it's famously an equivalent definition. If the OP (or any reader) has to use another definition, they can use constructions taking from equivalence proofs of the definitions and apply them (mechanically) to this solution.

Comment: @Raphael Yes, obvously. I just wanted to stress (if I'm able to reconstruct my thoughts from over a year ago correctly...) that the OP asked for "a context-sensitive (not just length-increasing) grammar" - which this certainly is not. Any length-increasing grammar can be easily transformed into context-sensitive form, but as it was asked explicitly for a context-sensitive one, I thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: @lukas.coenig My point is that some sources may give Kuroda normal form as definition for CSGs. We don't the OP's source.

Comment: @Raphael I don't think so. The term "context-sensitive" specifically states how the rule structure should be: stating a context in which a non-terminal may be replaced by a string. See also here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar#Kuroda_normal_form

Comment: @Raphael Although I admit that the German Wikipedia DOES say something about "monotone" and "cs" grammars not being always distinguished. This makes sense when focussing on the languages produced by these grammars, of course.

Comment: @Raphael. You wrote that the epsilon rule $S_3\to\epsilon$ is easy to fix. I find it very hard to fix without making the grammar a non-context-sensitive grammar. How would you fix it?

Comment: @Barbara if I'm not missing something, one would just implement the $S_i$ as markers on the other non-terminals (i.e. create one non-terminal per combination). That gets messy, but it's not hard.

Comment: @Raphael. Thank you, but I don't think it is that easy. Consider the word $aaa$ for ex. To obtain that word, you have to start with $S\to SA_1A_2A_3$. The length of this sentential form is 4, while the length of $aaa$ is 3, so somewhere down the road you would have to decrease the length of the sentential form. However, this is not allowed in a context-sensitive grammar since it is non-decreasing, that is, for every production $x\to y$, one must have $\|x\|\le \|y\|$. If I'm not wrong, this means that the solution of jnalanko is all wrong. However, I can't seem to find a correct solution...

Comment: @Barbara It seems we're misunderstanding each other. I meant to refactor the whole grammar; you'd start with $A_1^0A_2A_3$; upper indices $i$ would replace "right of $S_i$". Abstractly speaking, all constant-sized "overhead" can be folded into special symbols. (I think.)

Comment: @Barbara At this point, I think you should open a new question. If the way from here to what you need is not as simple as I thought it was, a discussion in the comments is not the right way to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

The answer for your specific example is there, but the general
question remains.

In very many years, in both theoretical and applied computer science,
I do not recall having to write a CS grammar as such.

Still, if I may give an advice, it should not be seen at all like
producing a CF grammar, were you must contrive the rules to get
everything in place and coordinated exactly right as it is produced.

CS grammars are a lot more algorithmic, and you can pretty much mimic a
Turing machine (working in finite space, proportional to input size,
which means Linear Bounded Automaton - LBA) in order to move things
around as needed. So it is much more a programming exercise.

You can pretty much generates the first ingredients to build one of
the words in the language, then move them around algorithmically.  You
can use special symbols (possibly in various flavors corresponding to
finite state) to act as heads that you move around with appropriate
rules, do as to check what is to be done. And so on.

A good reading may be to look at the proof of equivalence between CSG
languages and LBA languages, i.e. the CS languages.

Remember that nearly all algorithms that we work with can be performed
by a LBA, hence correspond to a CSG definable language. That should
give you an idea of the available algorithmic power.

But a bit of imagination helps elegant solutions, as in the example
you gave.

Comment: So, for the language provided in User_1234's question, how might one go about designing an LBA for it? I'm only experienced with designing Turing Machines for languages with separators; For example: $\{w\#w\#w:w \in \{a,b\}^*\}$, which seems to make things easier.

Comment: @DavidSmith For $www$ there is a simple specific solution given in the first Ran G
comment and with details in the previous solution. This is a bit
different from TM which are usually constructed as acceptors
(recognizers), while here you want a constructor. One other way to do
it is to generate a string $w$, then to add 2 symbols $#$ on one side,
and then replace each symbol $#$ by a copy of the string $w$. This is
more complex, but it will work for any number of copies of $w$, just
by increasing the number of symbols $#$.

Comment: @DavidSmith A LBA is an acceptor, which you "program" pretty much like a TM. In
this case, if you are given $www$ and want to recognize it, you can
simply have a first computation that somehow (many ways) count the
symbols to place the two $#$ at the right place. Alternatively, you
can rely on non determinism, and place the two $#$ in random places on
the input string. One choice of them will be good, if the string is in
the language.

Answer (score 1):

this is just an additional answer that can be thought of as a general solution. CSLs, context sensitive languages are modelled by LBAs, [linear bounded automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_bounded_automaton). a LBA is a Turing machine that can accept or reject given a work tape that is no larger than a constant times the size of the input tape. so if you can figure out a computer program that can process the input in constant space, then its a CSL. idea: a program that would work for this problem would do something like enumerate permutations in constant space.