# Grammar for square numbers in unary

Tags: formal-grammars, context-sensitive

I have to write a grammar for the following language:
$$\{1^{n^2} \mid n\geq 1 \}$$
I am having trouble figuring out the production rules. I was thinking of using the fact that $n^2$ can be written as the sum of first $n$ odd numbers but couldn't proceed any further.

Comment: Your language is not context-free. What kind of grammar are you interested in? A context-sensitive grammar?

Comment: The following paper gives a context-sensitive grammar for $\{0^{F_n} : n \geq 0\}$, where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci paper: http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/31-1/mootha.pdf. Perhaps this is useful for you.

Comment: Context-free-grammar is out of question. As Yuval mentions you can write a context-sensitive grammar.  First try to construct an LBA.  That will help in understanding how you can go about writing CSG.

Comment: Any kind of grammar would work but if a context-sensitive is possible, I would like that! I am looking at the paper. :)

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: I looked at the paper but its too difficult for me currently. I doubt the above problem requires so many production rules. :/

Comment: @Shreesh We haven't covered LBA yet. :(

Comment: @Shreesh Yes, I understand your point but we have just started with constructing grammar for a given language so I really doubt my professor would give a problem which would require a lot of production rules. Do you have any ideas regarding the problem I have posted? :)

Comment: @Pranav look at copy grammars. Every time you make a copy you add two symbols, so you will have $1^1-1^3-1^5-1^7...$. If you give your attempt, I may suggest further, and if it is too difficult for you, then I will provide a solution. I have already got a couple of warnings from moderators not to encourage undesirable posting behavior ;-)

Comment: @Shreesh I was looking for something like that. Searching for copy grammar, I found only one example which is a bit complicated for me to understand. Can you please write a solution? :3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B$ stand for the beginning marker, $A$ stands for a single 1 to be added later, $D$'s are copier markers and $E$ be the end marker. $F$, $G$, $I$, $H$ markers are used to properly generate all $A$'s. The following is not the most efficient grammar, but it will do.

Context free grammar rules:

$S \rightarrow BAFUE\ |\ \epsilon$
$U \rightarrow UD \ | \ D$

Non-contracting grammar rules:

$FD \rightarrow DG$
$AD \rightarrow D1A$
$1D \rightarrow D1$
$A1 \rightarrow 1A$
$BD \rightarrow BH$
$H1 \rightarrow 1H$
$HA\rightarrow AI$
$IA\rightarrow AI$
$IG \rightarrow AAF$

Now some non non-contracting rules:

$FE \rightarrow E$
$B \rightarrow \epsilon$
$AE \rightarrow E$
$E \rightarrow \epsilon$

Though this grammar has four non non-contracting rules, I have left them as it is, to help understanding. With a little effort we can convert it into a non-contracting grammar and then to a context-sensitive-grammar.

$IG \rightarrow AAF$ is the important rule, every time it adds two extra $AA$'s to be later substituted by 1's.

Comment: I was not looking for most efficient grammar rules. I was interested in how we can use simple copy grammars and the fact that $n^2 = 1 + 3 + 5 ...$ to get a (sufficiently) easy grammar.

Comment: I used non non-contracting to emphasize that what we really want are non-contracting rules and these rules are anomaly.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a head that walks over the sentential form and expands some non-terminals it finds. What should the head do?

> Start with a single $A$ and the head to the left of it, i.e. $\circ A$. The head passed from left to right and expands every $A$ it finds to a $1$ and a new $A$ -- and the last $A$ spawns a a new $A$ and triggers that the head copies the last block of $1$s.

How do you move the head?

> With rules of the form $\circ A \to A \circ$.

How do you control what the head does where?

> Introduce marked copies of symbols. For instance, the last $A$ could be a $\hat A$.