# Could someone please explain this language to me and its grammar?

Tags: formal-grammars

This is the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl6qx.png

This was a problem I saw and I really have 0 clue what the Language means the (**) part, and its solution.

I was wondering if anyone could please help me?

I do know what grammars are and how to read them, but this one was confusing and what I really want to know is how one would approach a problem like this. If I was given this problem, I wouldn't even know where to start.

Thank you.

Comment: I've no idea what $**$ means, either: it should have been defined earlier in whatever document you took the question from. Otherwise, you seem to be asking "How can I find a grammar for an arbitary given language." That's a very broad question to which the only real answer is "Check the textbooks for general advice and then get lots of practice." Finding things like grammar and automata is essentially a creative act. If there was a straightforward recipe, we'd have programmed that into a computer by now.

Comment: @David Richerby Unfortunately, the ** wasn't defined anywhere I searched. Perhaps it means a^(n^2)? But, could you explain how you would approach this problem itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grammar for square numbers in unary](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53530/grammar-for-square-numbers-in-unary)

Comment: [Don't post an image and expect us to decipher it.](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their)

Answer (score 3):

The notation ** is an old way of writing exponentiation ^.

The grammar is a type-0 grammar, where any string can be replaced by another. It actually comes close to a context-sensitive grammar (or better monotonous grammar) except for the last three productions.

Generating squares is usually done using the recurrence $(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n +1$ so the strings always contain a $n$ specially distinguished symbols so one can add the double amount of $2n$ to get the next square. After adding 1 of course.

Here I guess this is seen in the production $M_R A \to aA M_R$: the symbol $M_R$ moves over the string and adds an $a$ for each $A$.