# Grammar/Chomsky-Type for $L = \{ww \mid w \in \{a,b\}^*\}$

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, chomsky-hierarchy

I've been given the following task and have tried a few things, but none seem to result in what is required.

$L = \{ww \mid w \in \{a,b\}^*\}$

What Chomsky-Type is $L$? Provide a grammar fulfilling that Type.

It can't be context-free, since that wouldn't allow us to force that we write each symbol twice at the right place. Also it shouldn't be Type-0, since I suspect that rules that satisfy context-sensitive should be fine(namely all rules fulfill $u \rightarrow p$ with $\mid u\mid \leq \mid p\mid$)

Now I've tried to find a working grammar that fulfills Type-1, but I fail at getting the right order of $a,b$ in the second word.

How could I go about this and am I even right with suspecting to be able to find a Type-1 grammar?

Comment: I'm fairly sure we already have this on the site somwhere. Also, [related question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/43639/98).

Comment: @Raphael That's an awesome topic, thank you. Since the accepted answer is of a TM, I suspect that my assumption that $L$ is of type-1 is false, else they'd use a pushdown automaton, right?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33853/how-to-generate-a-context-sensitive-grammar-for-www describes an approach.

Comment: @rici Thank you so much, that is a great answer, very generic for any Language $L$ with $\{w^k \mid w \in \Sigma^* \} \forall k\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @rici Note that LBAs are eqivalent to type-1, not TMs. Try to figure out if you can implement Klaus Draeger's sketch wthout using additional tape!

Comment: @raphael: yes, i know. Opinions differ, but for me constructing TMs (and similar) is an activity closer to [codegolf.se] than to  [cs.se]. Anyway, this question asks for a grammar, not an automaton, and the answer I linked to provides one, which is equivalent to a Type-1 grammar. (The rest of the niceties of the various equivalents to Chomsky's CSG definition is too large for this margin and rather boring after all these years.) Perhaps you intended to address the OP?

Comment: @Raphael Yes, you answered the question "[Context-sensitive grammar for the language of words concatenated with themselves](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/13345)".

Comment: @rici If you have an LBA, you can use the standard construction.